# Как установить Anaconda c python 3.8 под Win10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Установлена последняя версия Anaconda 3.9.7, многие приложения выше 3.8 плохо поддерживают. Как установить Anaconda с python 3.8 на win 10 или навсегда задаунгрейдить последнюю версию до нужной?

Лучшее что нашла:

```
conda create -n downgrade python=3.8 anaconda
conda activate downgrade
```

Однако downgrade слетает после перезапуска и приходится запускать заново

Может есть какая-то волшебная ссылка по которой можно скачать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ссылке все версии Anaconda

https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

Конкретная версия python в Anaconda не указана, но по датам, можно подобрать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Проще на самом сайте в Files посмотреть: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files . Там конкретные версии Python указаны, по версии можно отфильтровать нужное, например: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.8.13 - там берете win64